# How to change PDF margin while converting .docx to pdf using opensagres

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi, pdf-conversion

I'm using this code to convert an `XWPFDocument` to `PDF`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();

PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(xwpfDocument, baos, options);
```

The converter is setting wrong margins on the pdf. Here is the original `.docx`:

[image]

And this is the `pdf` after conversion:

[image]

How can I retain the original left and right margins?

Comment: Margins _and_ individual table column widths. Maybe a conversion **docx-to-html** + **html-to-pdf** would do better, as html is a better "understood" format.

Comment: @sam-ziggler, you can try to adjust page margins using [next approach >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52466352/how-to-change-margins-when-converting-with-apache-poi/52471740#52471740), but need to take into account that PDF converter will not provide ideal result anyway.